# Cannot connect to SQL Server (The Network path was not found)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to connect to a sql server and its not allowing me to. This just recently started happening from what I can tell nothing was changed. The TCP port (1433) is enabled and allowed access through the firewall, the Named Pipes is enabled. I can ping the IP address of the SQL Server I am trying to connect to. I am running out of ideas fast!

Here is the error:

> Cannot connect to (MyServerName)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)
>
> The network path was not found

Comment: What does your **connection string** look like that causes this error?

Comment: I'm unsure where to find the connection string, im just trying to login to the sql server @marc_s

Comment: @marc_s Connecting To (My IP Address)...Could not open connection to the host, on port 143
3: Connect failed

Comment: Is it a "named instance" of SQL Server? Or a default instance? Named instances run on dynamic ports by default (although they can be configured to run on a static port). Default instances by default run on port 1433.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was resolved. The company that was hosting the SQL Server I was trying to reach had blocked our cloud server IP address. Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: How did you figure out this was the root cause?

Comment: I'm currently facing a similar issue. As it turns out the hosting company had to whitelist my ip. I only found out about it by ringing them and endlessly complaining.

Comment: I pinged their server in which the SQL Server lives on and it failed!

Answer (score 0):

Map your shared folder on both Sql Servers [ primary and secondary Sql server ] and try again to configure file log shipping may this help because in my scenario is working for me